# Add status icons over file icons in Explorer, like Dropbox or SVN in Air

Tags: air, icons, overlay

I am new to Adobe AIR. Please help

I want to Add status icons over file icons in Explorer, like Dropbox or SVN. I am developing anappliation like dropbox in Adobe AIR for MAC and Windows.

I think it is common for both OS Mac and Windows both OS support AIR so i have choice this tool.

I have two queries.

1. Add status icons over file icons in Explorer, like Dropbox or SVN.
2. Folder watcher you have and idea about that and any class and utility for that.

Comment: I think you should go native if you need that (c#/c++ and ObjC). Overlay icons cannot be done with flex/flash out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think AIR is the correct solution for this. Although it would be possible to poll a  directory and compare its last known structure to its current one, I imagine this would be very inefficient in both Actionscript 3 and Javascript.

Languages such a Java in their latest major release have utilities for [directory monitoring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview) 'out  of the box' and have the benefit of being able to delegate these tasks to different threads.

To give another example something like [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) which monitors directories and dynamically changes the icons is written in C++.